# SQL query returning error only when CASE WHEN is used

Tags: sql

I have the sql code below and the case when statement is always returning the 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric'. But if I comment it out then the statement runs successfully even though the same code is used in the first column.

```
SELECT CAST(DATA1 AS DECIMAL(10,5)), AMOUNT, CASE WHEN NAME ='A' THEN CAST(DATA1 AS DECIMAL(10,5)) ELSE '0' END FROM TEST
```

If I run as is above, it fails. If I comment out the Case when piece then it runs successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling it to display two different data types in the same column. Try;

```
SELECT CAST(DATA1 AS DECIMAL(10,5)), AMOUNT, 
CASE 
  WHEN NAME LIKE 'A' THEN CAST(DATA1 AS DECIMAL(10,5)) 
  ELSE CAST(0.0 AS DECIMAL(10,5)) END FROM TEST
```

Answer (score 2):

Your CASE statement is trying to return two different types, DECIMAL(10,5) and varchar.

It needs to return one type, so instead of having '0' just use 0.0.